# Qt5: How to do a cleanup manager (1 or more tasks) that run periodically to do cleaning-job?

Tags: qt, timer, task, jobs

I am using Qt5 under Windows7.
I need to implement some kind of cleanup manager for my application.
It will be "activated" let's say once per hour, in order to perform some cleanup job(s): trim history if it's > 1000 lines, delete records form a database if older than 30 days and other things like this...
How should I do it in order to be flexible (to allow future cleaning tasks to be added later) and also to have minimal/reasonable impact on the application performance, i.e.: application is kinda multitasking server doing TCP connections and database connections, etc and I don't want the cleanup manager/task(s) to have some negative impact on the overall application speed/performance.
But ok, let's say a short time drop in performance would be acceptable as long as the user/client won't complain about such aspects :)
I am novice in Qt programming... I was thinking about using QTimer that periodically triggers a QTask/Qthread or something...?
Regards, Stanley.

Answer (score 1):

You are on right track you can use QTimer to trigger a cleanup slot in you cleanup manager.
you can keep adding different slots for different cleanup activity.
Looking at you query it seems it better to have all you cleanup task in threads so that cleanup will be done async and will have less impact on performance.

Comment: So, let me synthesize your idea: You say I should have something like: ClassA with (QTimer Ta; SIGNAL(Ta) ...} and ClassB with (QTimer Tb; SIGNAL(Tb) ...}, etc. and then a Qthread with {SLOT(a), SLOT(b), etc.}.  Is it correct?  Is one single QThread ok to do the cleanup job or should I spread it in more threads?! ...

Comment: Are you serious or just pulling my leg. Having ClassA or ClassB totally depends on your implementation. But QTimer already have signal timeout() which you can connect to QThread's slot start(). Now having one thread or multiple threads also depends about you implementation and requirement. But you can have QTimer to connect to multiple threads.

Comment: I am serious and I'm not pulling anything here. Probably my bad English? Anyway, let me try to explain. Simplifying things: let's say we have 2 classes ClassA and ClassB, each class has its own Qtimer that triggers the timeout() signal. For ex let;s say timeout signal of classA is to clean the history and the timeout signal of classB is to clean the database. You said "connect to QThread's slot strart()". Suppose there is only one single thread that does all the cleanup work. But then how would this thread know what to do? Clean history or database? Its slot start() doesn't have any parameter.